# Does Spyder work with Python GTK in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, gtk, spyder

Does Spyder work with Python GTK in Ubuntu? Or is Spyder Qt only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [its project page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder#runtime-dependencies), PyQt is a hard requirement of Spyder, while GTK doesn't show up. That sounds very much like it's Qt (and terminal) only.

Comment: Yes this confirms my suspicions. Thank you. I was looking for a way to use python programs I made on Windows with PyScripter and GTK. Apparently PyScripter is not available in Ubuntu.